# Building an e-commerce store ( not on WP )

Tags: database, service, e-commerce

I will need to build an ecommerce store. I cant really wrap it around my head so far, but my main vision:

I would pay a monthly fee for a solution (something like woocommerce or shopify) so I can keep my products online in their database. Also this solution would have all the needed things bundled (like emails, order trackings, inventory, reimbursement). It would generate an email or other sign to my client when an order happens. I can imagine this happening on Wordpress with some pre-built templates.
Here comes the second part, because I would prefer to build the front-end on my own. Do You know any solution where I can simply communicate with GET / POST requests to the endpoints. So when webshop loads the products would be rendered with CSS to the users. In case of order (linked to STRIPE most probably) the required details (SKU, Quantity, user info) is saved and sent towards the solution.

How would You build it? What would You recommend as a service?

Regards,
Koppany

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com could be a better site for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm much aware of one company known as Scale Labs which provides the cross-border e-commerce solutions and all kinds of services related the e-commerce sector.

You can also take the help of alternatives to Scale Labs which includes Pitney Bowes, Acommerce asia, etc but personally, I have gone through the Scale Labs. They helped me from scratch and now am earning a good profit from my store. Here's the link to their official website: [Cross-Border e-commerce solutions](http://www.thescalelabs.com/).

If you are still confused then let me know. Thanks